# ASP.NET MVC - View to edit data from a joined SQL table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Sorry, I am new to ASP.NET MVC and am working on a web application that was partially completed by somebody else who is no longer able to help.  I have a view to edit a news item which looks like this:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is remove the section 'Content' and replace it with the section 'NewsContent'.

It seems to show the correct data from SQL database but I can't get it to show the HTML editor.  The data for this new section comes from a linked SQL table called `NewsArtical.cs`

This is my code:

Models:

```
public partial class News
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastModified { get; set; }

    public virtual NewsArtical NewsArtical { get; set; }
}

public partial class NewsArtical
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string NewsContent { get; set; }
    public virtual News News { get; set; }
}
```

`NewsController`:

```
// GET: News/Edit/5
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return RedirectToRecordNotFound();
        //return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    News news = await _entities.News.FindAsync(id);

    if (news == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(news);
}
```

View `Edit.cshtml`:

```
@model CELIntranet.Models.News
@{
    ViewBag.Title = string.Format("Edit News Article: {0}", Model.ID);
}

@Html.Partial("_ContentToolbarPartial", (object)@ViewBag.Title)
    <body>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control focusme" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", cols = 80, rows = 10 } })

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsArtical.NewsContent, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsArtical.NewsContent, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", cols = 80, rows = 10 } })

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsArtical.NewsContent, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                @Html.TextBox("Date", Model.Date.ToShortDateString(), (object)new { @class = "form-control form-control-minwidth" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastModified, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastModified, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control form-control-minwidth", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastModified, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" />
                <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" onclick="history.go(-1);return true;" />
            </div>
        }
    </body>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/summernote")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#Description").summernote({
                minHeight: 200
            });

            $('#Date').datetimepicker({
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                showClose: true,
                showClear: true,
                toolbarPlacement: 'top'
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Content box in your screenshot has the HTML Editor added in the JavaScript, in this code:

```
 $("#Description").summernote({
                minHeight: 200
            });
```

Explanation: The Content box is has the ID "Description" in the HTML, and a JQuery function named named 'summernote' is called that supposably adds the HTML editor.
To add the HtmlEditor to the NewsContent text box you can do something similar, such as adding:

```
 $("#NewsContent").summernote({
                minHeight: 200
            });
```

Comment: I found this website for summernote: https://summernote.org/

Comment: Ezra, thanks for the pointer.  I have adjusted as suggested but the editor is still not showing.  In the view, I have is coded like this

Comment: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsArtical.NewsContent, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", cols = 80, rows = 10 } })

Comment: check the html itself and find the id of the textbox for the NewsContent.  Make sure that the javascript looks correct, and check for any errors in the console.

Comment: Ezra, I change the ID as suggested and this now works.  Thank you for help.   $("#NewsArtical_NewsContent").summernote({
                minHeight: 200
            });